# How to calculate the maximum total data size for a Minio cluster?

Tags: minio

For a Minio cluster of 4 nodes with erasure code enabled and each node having 4 x 1TB drives (total of 16 TB disk size):

- what is the maximum size of data I can upload assuming that I have 8 data and 8 parity disks?

When I read the documentation of Minio, I understand that every object is replicated across all nodes and disks. We can upload 2 TB data for each node (other 2 TB being parity). And if all of the objects are replicated on all disks then other nodes will also store the same objects. Then I can only store 2 TB of data with 16 TB of available disk size. Is that correct?

Note: I know that I can increase the data size by decreasing the number of parity disks. I ask for the specific case of half data half parity disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have equal parity and data, then you have a 2x overhead, meaning your usable capacity is half your raw disk size.  All objects are erasure coded across disks in a given erasure set, with a maximum of 16 disks per erasure set (and possibly many erasure sets), so it is not replication in the way you are thinking.  From [this doc](https://github.com/minio/minio/tree/master/docs/erasure/storage-class) you can see the formula for other parity to data ratios.  The basic formula is total drives (N) / data drives (D).